# Mybatis - Error when specify "useGeneratedKeys" for Hsql

Tags: java, hsqldb, mybatis

Inside `Mybatis` mapper file, for `<insert>` statement, when add property `useGeneratedKeys="true"`, will get error:

> org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: id

The configuration works for `Postgresql` and `Mysql`, but not `Hsql`.

The **id** column in `hsql` is defined as:

`id BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1) PRIMARY KEY`

When remove property `useGeneratedKeys="true"`, it works.

But why this would happen?

Comment: I'm using it and it works. I'm using it with Postgres compatiblity (using BigSerial) but it is translated to Hsql equivalent, so this should work. (http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/compatibility-chapt.html#coc_compatibility_postgres)

Comment: @Pau I tested it, it don't work with `Hsql`, maybe in Hsql, the implementation of `IDENTITY` is special, and cause the issue.

Comment: @Pau The issue is caused by special case sensitivity on names in `hsqldb`, refer to @fredt's answer & comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the character case of "id". Try defining the column in the database as

```
 "id" BIGINT GENERATED ...
```

Or alternatively, define the column as ID (upper case) in MyBatis.

Comment: The questions says clearly that the `id` is already lower case.

Comment: Your SQL is converted to to uppercase by HSQLDB. You need to use double quotes around `id` to force lowercase.

Comment: Adding double quotes on column name when creating table won't solve the issue, but use uppercase for `keyColumn` property of `<insert>` solved the issue, e.g `keyColumn="ID"`.

Comment: By the way, if I add property `sql.ignore_case=true` in connection url, it also tips me `id` can't be found, this is a little wield, not sure how hsqldb handles case sensitivity, I didn't found a comprehensive document on that.

Comment: sql.ignore_case is for strings in query conditions such as `john` in `WHERE name = 'john'`

Comment: Ok, do there have anyway to make `hsqldb` behavior the same as `postgresql` on case sensitivity, I mean case-insensitive on names (e.g table, column, etc).

Comment: If you do not use double quotes, the SQL is always case-insensitive, but it is the JDBC method for generated keys that is case-sensitive. Future versions may allow case-insensitive treatment of generated keys.

Comment: Ok, I think you mean there a kind of object for generated key, and name of the generated key is uppercase `ID`, and that's case-sensitive, hope I understood it correctly.

Comment: Yes. In SQL, unquoted identifiers are converted to uppercase. So the name of the column is in uppercase.